# How to create a Six Bar Linkage with the Stephenson Topology

Tags: mechanical-engineering, civil-engineering, kinematics

I wanted to clarify a point in Mechanical Engineering. To create a six-bar linkage with the Stephenson Topology, do I just have to pick 5 joint locations and connect them with binary links? Then I place two joints on different sides of this pentagon and connect these two joints with another binary link. Will this get me a valid six-bar linkage? Thanks!

Comment: Stephenson I, II or III? Anyway how the actual sizes are depends on what motion you need, and if you need a motion or force transfer. Also what is an unvalid linkage? Yes you can connect 5 joints so that its not a six bar linkage. Please draw an image.

Comment: Plot the movement of the joints…

Comment: On Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six-bar_linkage#:~:text=In%20mechanics%2C%20a%20six-bar%20linkage%20is%20a%20mechanism,links%2C%20and%20a%20binary%20link%20supports%20two%20joints. It says that to create a valid six bar linkage with the Stephenson topology, we just need to create a pentagon and then connect two sides of the pentagon with a binary link, but intuitively this doesn't seem like it would always work. Also, by a valid linkage I mean that it gets a full coupler curve.